# discord.py os.environ doesn't work for bot token

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

so I have this code:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


client.run(token)
```

The 'DISCORD_TOKEN' is stored in another file '.env' in the same directory which is:

```
#. env file
DISCORD_TOKEN={SSS}
```

Now whenever I try to run this code, I end up getting these erros:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 222, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 598, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 579, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 542, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 400, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 262, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

But when I simply use 
`token = 'DSDS'` instead of the .getenv, the code works and my bot is online.

Any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out where I was wrong. I should have used '' instead of {} outside the token in my dotenv file.